# How to convert ant build script to sbt?

Tags: scala, ant, sbt, scalaxb

I'd like to convert the [html5boilerplate build script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/) from ant to sbt.  I've spent a few minutes with with scalaxb, but with no luck so far.  Doesn't seem to be an xsd for ant build scripts.

Is there a better way to convert an XML build script to Scala code, specifically sbt?  Failing that, is there *any* way besides by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That build uses the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) library in order to add lots of lovely XML based programming constructs into the build.....

If the original build author had stuck to core ANT there might have been some hope of writing a translater..... With [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) in the mix I reckon it would be simpler to just translate by hand.

Comment: Thanks, that's the conclusion I've come to after more googling as well.  :(